# removing space and retaining the new line?

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to replace all the spaces from a string , but i need to keep the new line character as it ?

```
choiceText=choiceText.replace(/\s/g,'');

india
aus //both are in differnt line
```

is giving as `indaus`

i want newline should retain and remove the s

Comment: `indaus`: hmm, where has the `ia` gone?

Comment: Your input is `india\naus`, your output is `indaus`: you probably forgot `ia`.

Answer (score 6):

`\s` means any whitespace, including newlines and tabs.  is a space. To remove just spaces:

```
choiceText=choiceText.replace(/ /g,''); // remove spaces
```

You could remove "any whitespace *except* newlines"; [most regex flavours count `\s` as `[ \t\r\n]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), so we just take out the `\n` and the  `\r` and you get:

```
choiceText=choiceText.replace(/[ \t]/g,''); // remove spaces and tabs
```

Comment: tht gives the same result. without line

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `\s` (any whitespace) for this. Use a character set instead: `[ \t\f\v]`

Comment: choiceText=choiceText.replace([\t\f\v]/g,'') .is it like this?

Comment: Yes, just don't forget the initial "/" :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `\s` regex pattern matches all whitespace chars. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes), `\s` is "*equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]`*".

The easiest way to subtract a line feed, a newline, char from `\s` is to use a reverse, `\S`, *shorthand character class*, put it into a *negated character class*, `[^\S]` and add `\n` into it, that is, `[^\S\n]`.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
console.log(
  "india\naus \f\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff."
     .replace(/[^\S\n]+/g, ''))
```